# Android how to increase Application memory using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

In general applications will be allocated a max of 26MB. But i need it to be more. For a specific reason. And i know the problems of allocating more memory to a particular application. Since it is my need. Can anybody help me writing code for allocation of a specific chunk of memory to a particular application. I know that it can be done through NDK. But don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The managed heap is capped at a device-specific limit, based on the available physical memory and the size of the screen (since bitmaps are one of the primary consumers of RAM).  This limit is around 48MB on recent devices.

If you set `android:largeHeap` on a recent device, that number increases substantially, to perhaps 256MB.  There is no way to expand the managed heap beyond the largeHeap limit.

The native heap, accessible from native code built with the NDK, does not have a fixed limit.  The larger you are though, the more likely your app is to be killed by the kernel.  The kernel tries very hard not to kill foreground apps, but if the user switches away briefly a memory-hog app is likely to die.

Bottom line: try to use as little memory as possible.

Comment: "android:largeHeap" is not the solution. In-fact i have used that too. But my application is special. So i need NDK to increase the memory. All i want is a sample to control memory using malloc and releasing it through the application. And i need not worry about other applications that will be running, because i know that its my application which is the only application running on the device. So if you have something in this regard please help me out. Other wise i know all that you have reproduced here.